# How to add buttons inside div in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have created three divs in my R Shiny App and need to add buttons inside those divs.  If I try a usual HTML approach I would do something like this:

[image]

```
div("Here is some text inside the div", style = "color:green; font-size:20px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; margin: 10px 0; padding: 10px; width: 700px", <input type='submit' value='Dismiss'/>)
```

but this obviously fails because divs are done differently than regular html in R Shiny.

How can I get 2 buttons inside my div (like the image) in R Shiny App?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `HTML()` function to render regular HTML. Or you can use the `shiny::tags` variable to create any valid HTML tag a la

```
div("Somee text", style="someStyle", 
  tags$input(type="submit", value="Dismiss")
)
```

I find that Shiny-ifying all the UI code ends up being cleaner than mixing and matching HTML and Shiny functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that once you want to exercise a bit more control over the layout, styling, and interactions in a Shiny app its best to switch the ui.R output over to html/css/js that you control.

http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#html-ui